# Regular expression for matching repeated substring

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I need to get URLs from `background-image` value in HTML style parameter, in this stage I have this regular (`URL` is long regular matching valid URLS so I omit it here for simplification):

```
background-image\s*?\:\s*?(url\(\s*?(['"])?\s*?(URL)\s*?(\2)?\s*?\)([,]?))+
```

It matches only the first occurrence of URL, I think I've allowed to match all occurrences (but obviously I haven't). What am I doing wrong?

**Input may looks like this:**

```
String txt = "<div style=\"background-image: url('A'), url(B);\">fooo</div>";
```

and what I need to achieve with my regular:

1. Check whether there is a `background-image` value followed with `*` spaces, then `:` (colon) and again `*` spaces.
2. Extract *all* values in `url()` pattern.

Now I am able to to get all values in `url()` pattern but I am not able to ensure that there is a `background-image` value.

Comment: Why am I donwvoted? Have I missed something? Please explain, thank you.

Comment: What is `background-image`? What is `style parameter`? What does the input look like? What do you want for expected output? What specifically is wrong with your solution? All good things to include considering none of us know what you're trying to match this regex against.

Comment: I mean HTML parameter style, it specifies the input. And the rest information is mentioned in my question.

Comment: Can we see how you are using this regex? Also if `\2` is suppose to match quote used to surround URL (single or double) then it seems that you need to use `\3` - `(['"])` is third group.

Comment: I've added an example with more detailed input and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is fine, except for that it doesn't search for URL's it searches for the text URL. I've added a \d behind URL to demonstrate that your regex works:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("background-image\\s*?\\:\\s*?(url\\(\\s*?(['\"])?\\s*?(URL\\d)\\s*?(\\2)?\\s*?\\)([,]?))+");
Matcher m = p.matcher("background-image: url(URL1); background-image: url(URL2)");
while( m.find() ){
    System.out.println(m.group(3));
}

Output: 
URL1
URL2
```

Comment: Thanks. There is only one "background-image" value but can be more "url(XYZ)" values.

Comment: Np. So what are you asking?

Comment: I've added an example with more detailed input and desired output.